# Why objects are not merged?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I would like to merge objects to one.

But the results is : `const articles` displays only the last object... why?

[image: capture d ecran 2018-11-16 a 15 27 14]

[image: capture d ecran 2018-11-16 a 15 27 07]

Comment: They all have a property named "edges", so the values overwrite the previous ones.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks! Could you make an officialy answer to validate and close the question please?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread syntax assignment works like `Object.assign()`. Your three objects each have a property called "edges".  When you "merge" them, the value of "edges" in each object is copied into the target, but it's a *shallow* copy. The runtime makes no attempt to do any sort of deeper combining of the array values, so you just end up with the last array copied.

If you want to merge (or concatenate, or whatever) the arrays, you'll have to do that with an explicit piece of code.

Comment: Thank you Pointy! I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

You cant have 3 different keys with same name
Do you expect `{ edges: {}, edges: {}, edges:{} }` ?

Or maybe `{ ...infographics.edges, ...posts.edges, ...pulses.edges }` makes it correct?

Comment: Yeah, the second one. I understand now ^^ Thank you

Comment: No problem...be sure to come back here later, if you dont need help, maybe others need yours. Good luck